# Visual Studio Macro: How to perform "File -> Save All" programatically

Tags: visual-studio, macros

I am looking for the equivalent of running "File -> Save All" before certain Rake macros.

What I have so far is:

```
Private Sub Pre_Rake()
        Dim i As Integer

        DTE.Documents.SaveAll()

        For i = 1 To DTE.Solution.Projects.Count
            If Not DTE.Solution.Projects.Item(i).Saved Then
                DTE.Solution.Projects.Item(i).Save()
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

DTE.Documents.SaveAll works fine, but the for loop does not save the project files as I would expect.

If I make a copy of a file in the solution explorer, that file is not included in the project file (.CSPROJ) after Pre_Rake() runs. I would still have to press CTRL-SHIFT-S or File -> Save All.

So, how to Save All with a Visual Studio Macro?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently `DTE.Documents.SaveAll` doesn't save all open documents (maybe it saves only ones belonging to open projects). Try using

```
DTE.ExecuteCommand("File.SaveAll")
```

which is exactly like doing File -> Save All.

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in understanding why the For loop didn't work, it is because we also have to loop through the project items:

```
Sub SaveAllFiles()
    For i = 1 To DTE.Solution.Projects.Count
        If Not DTE.Solution.Projects.Item(i).Saved Then
            DTE.Solution.Projects.Item(i).Save()
        End If
        For j = 1 To DTE.Solution.Projects.Item(i).ProjectItems.Count
            If Not DTE.Solution.Projects.Item(i).ProjectItems.Item(j).Saved Then
                DTE.Solution.Projects.Item(i).ProjectItems.Item(j).Save()
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```